# Convergence in measure implies uniform convergence on a set of finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence

Question is :

> Does there exist a sequence $\left(f_k\right)$ of Lebesgue measurable functions such that $f_k$ converges to $0$ in measure in $\mathbb{R}$ but no subsequence converges uniformly on any subset of positive measure?

See that $\left(f_k\right)$ converges to $0$ in measure implies there exists a subsequence $\left(f_{n_k}\right)$ that converges point wise almost every where to $0$.

Then by Egoroff's theorem we can say that on a set of finite measure, $\left(f_{n_k}\right)$ converges uniformly almost everywhere to $0$.

I am not sure if we can say it converges uniformly and not just almost everywhere.

Comment: 1. By Egoroff's theorem we can say that on a set of finite measure, if $(f_{n_k})$ that converges point wise almost every where to $0$, then $(f_{n_k})$ converges almost uniformly to $0$. Please,  note that  almost uniform convergence is **not** the same as  uniform convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: 2. It is a known result that if a sequence $(f_k)$ of lebesgue measurable functions converges to $0$ in measure then there is subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which converges almost uniformly.  As a consequence, there is a set of  of finite measure where $(f_{n_k})$  converges uniformly to $0$.

Comment: @Ramiro : I understand 1st point but not second point

Comment: 2. It is a known result that if a sequence $(f_k)$ of lebesgue measurable functions converges to $0$ in measure then there is subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which converges almost uniformly to $0$.  It means, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a set measurable set $A$ such that $m(A)<\varepsilon$ and  $(f_{n_k})$ converges o $0$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}-A$. So the answer to your question is NO, there is not a sequence as you described in your question. (See, for instance, Bartle, *Elements of Integration*, theorem 7.11 or Halmos, *Measure Theory*, section 22, theorem D).